# Creating a new entry in a specific section

Tags: plugin-development, entries

Let's say I created a section called, "Answers". In a custom plugin, I want to create an entry that should show up under the "Answers" tab in the CP entries page.

```
  $entry = new EntryModel();
  // How do I say, save this entry into the "Answers" channel?
  $saveIt = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

[image]

I have literally been reading Craft docs for the past hour, and have gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) you have has a [sectionId](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#sectionId) property you can set.  i.e.

```
 $entry = new EntryModel();
 $entry->sectionId = 1;
 $saveIt = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Note that there are other properties you'll need to set for it to pass validation.  So, if `$saveIt` is false after calling `saveEntry($entry)`, then call `$entry->getErrors()` to get an array of validation errors to fix.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I was confused how to refer to the section by name, which obviously is not possible.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich for future reference if it's really necessary for whatever reason to set something by handle (not name, the name is not unique) instead of the ID you could do `$entry->sectionId = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('handle')->id`